# Problema al iniciar modal por segunda vez

Tags: datatables, modal

Tengo un botón que llama a una función, y abre el modal al mismo tiempo. La primera vez que lo hago lo hace bien pero la segunda vez que ejecuto el botón me aparece este error en la consola:

> Type error: cannot read property parentnode of null.

Os dejo el código.

Este es el boton en html,  abro el modal.

```
<button type="button" id ="btnConvModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalConvenios"><strong>Ver Convenios</strong></button>
```

Llamo a la funcion

```
 $("#btnConvModal").on( "click", function() {
        busConveniosModal();
    });
```

Esta es la funcion:

```
function busConveniosModal(){ //Funcion que me lista una tabla con los convenios en un formulaio modal de administrador.
        $('#modalConvenios').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            tblConvenios = $('#tblConvenios').DataTable({ //Voy a necesitar la variable tabla
            "responsive": {
            "details": false,
            },

            autoWidth: false,
            "processing": true,
            "pagingType": "simple", //Hace que se muestren todos los elementos de la paginación               
            "destroy": "true", //Esto lo hago para que no me de error el datatable cuando lo vuelvo a inicializar una vez cargado.
            "language": {
                "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/Spanish.json"
            },

            "ajax": {
                "url": "php/AgrApp/cnv_emp.php", //web a la que llamo y hace el trabajo.
                "type": "POST", //Metodo usado por la funcion para pasar variable
                "dataSrc": "",
            },


            "columns": [
                {"defaultContent":" <button type='button' id=\"idConvenioAdmin\"  class='selectConv  btn btn-primary btn-xs '><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></button>","width": "3%"},
                { "data": "id"  },
                { "data": "name" },
                ]
            });
     });

}
```

Al hacer un alert("prueba"); al abrir el modal, me he dado cuenta de que la segunda vez que lo abre, me ejecuta el alert dos veces. le he puesto esta linea

```
$('#modalConvenios').off('shown.bs.modal');
```

y se ha solucionado el problema, lo que no entiendo es  la razón del problema, es como se se le fueran añadiendo  o almacenando  `$('#modalConvenios').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {` cada vez que lo llamo .

Comment: Intenta no asignar el evento *shown.bs.modal* al hacer click sobre el botón. Deja la función tal y como está pero llamala en el onReady de tu document y no en el evento onclick del botón. Prueba y me dices.

Comment: Además del error, podrías poner el stacktrace del mismo? en tu código no hay ningún `parentnode` que pueda fallar. Como dice @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas, el error seguramente venga de añadir 2 event handlers al mismo elemento.